# get the count of trigger in quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, triggers, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler along with spring in my application and i want to get the number of the execution when the trigger is fired (i.e) first time, second time, third time and so on. i want to get the number of trigger that has already executed. is there any way?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just to keep it simple: how about adding a variable to the job object which is ++'ed every time that job executed? For example:

```
private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void run() {
  counter.incrementAndGet();
  ...
}

public int getRunCount() {
  counter.get();
}
```

Other than that - I don't think there are any internal methods in Quartz to keep track of how many times the job ran.

Comment: yes after all the search i found that the quartz does not provide a api to get the count of the trigger, but from their documentation i found a similar method as above in clear example [link](http://http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/examples/Example4) that was very helpful and tanQ @Aramir

Comment: Just noting that this approach didn't work for me since Quartz creates a new instance of the job object for each execution. Here is an [updated link to the example](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/examples/Example4.html) showing persisting job data, such as an execution count.

Answer (score 1):

At this point of time, you can use `getTimesTriggered()` of `SimpleTrigger` or any `TimeIntervalTrigger` implementation of the `Trigger` Interface.  Please refer below documentation link. 
[DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/index.html)