# Is there are way for CronTriggerImpl to get how many times it have been triggered

Tags: java, cron, quartz

we can use SimpleTrigger getTimesTriggered to know how many times this schedule have been triggered, for CronTriggerImpl, is there a similar way to achieve this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240955/get-the-count-of-trigger-in-quartz-scheduler

Comment: I know this question, it is for simpleTrigger of getTimesTriggered, and if use JobDataMap to persist the count, it will only be calculated after execution is done like the annotation PersistJobDataAfterExecution shows

Answer (score 2):

> for CronTriggerImpl, is there a similar way to achieve this?

**TLDR no.**

But you can implement [JobListener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html) and register it with your scheduler like this:

```java
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(myJobListener);
```

That way, you will be notified everytime job started and finished.
You can retrieve Trigger instance from [JobExecutionContext](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html)

Or similarly you can do with [TriggerListener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html)

```java
scheduler.getListenerManager().addTriggerListener(myTriggerListener);
```

Comment: Just realize this is for the whole scheduler, if we have multiple jobs in this scheduler, then the count will be the total trigger counts of all jobs, I was searching for the count of each job schedule times

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example program based on @rkosegi suggestion.
Using `org.quartz.TriggerListener` or `org.quartz.JobListener`

**ByeJob.java**

```
public class ByeJob implements Job {

    private ByeService bs = new ByeService();

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        bs.sayGoodbye();
    }
}
```

**ByeService.java**

```
    public class ByeService {
    
        public void sayGoodbye() {
            System.out.println("Testing " + new Date());
        }
    }
```

Using **GlobalJobListner.java**

```
public class GlobalJobListner implements JobListener {

    private static final String TRIGGER_LISTENER_NAME = "GlobalJobListner";
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return TRIGGER_LISTENER_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    String triggerName = context.getTrigger().getKey().toString();
    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
    count.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("trigger : " + triggerName + " is fired and " + "total count=" + count.get());
    System.out.println("job : " + jobName + " is fired and " + "total count=" + count.get());

    }
.....................
}
```

or Using **GlobalTriggerListener.java**

```
    public class GlobalTriggerListener implements TriggerListener {
    
        private static final String TRIGGER_LISTENER_NAME = "GlobalTriggerListener";
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return TRIGGER_LISTENER_NAME;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
            String triggerName = context.getTrigger().getKey().toString();
        String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        count.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("trigger : " + triggerName + " is fired and " + "total count=" + count.get());
        System.out.println("job : " + jobName + " is fired and " + "total count=" + count.get());
}
    ................
    }
```

**Verify**

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ByeJob.class).withIdentity("byeJob", "group1").build();
            CronTriggerImpl trigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
            trigger.setName("T1");
            trigger.setCronExpression("0/5 * * * * ?");

            Scheduler scheduler2 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

            // register global trigger
            scheduler2.getListenerManager().addTriggerListener(new GlobalTriggerListener());

            // register global listner
            scheduler2.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new GlobalJobListner());

            scheduler2.start();
            scheduler2.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
13:46:43.402 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
13:46:43.408 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
13:46:45.004 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'group1.byeJob', class=com.example.demo.ByeJob
trigger : DEFAULT.T1 is fired and total count=1
job : group1.byeJob is fired and total count=1
trigger : DEFAULT.T1 is fired and total count=1
job : group1.byeJob is fired and total count=1
13:46:45.009 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
13:46:45.009 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group1.byeJob
Testing Fri Apr 22 13:46:45 IST 2022
13:46:50.002 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'group1.byeJob', class=com.example.demo.ByeJob
13:46:50.003 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
trigger : DEFAULT.T1 is fired and total count=2
job : group1.byeJob is fired and total count=2
trigger : DEFAULT.T1 is fired and total count=2
job : group1.byeJob is fired and total count=2
13:46:50.003 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job group1.byeJob
Testing Fri Apr 22 13:46:50 IST 2022
13:46:55.003 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'group1.byeJob', class=com.example.demo.ByeJob
trigger : DEFAULT.T1 is fired and total count=3
job : group1.byeJob is fired and total count=3
trigger : DEFAULT.T1 is fired and total count=3
job : group1.byeJob is fired and total count=3
```